# How do I get the system volume programatically

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

I want to get the system volume level to use programatically, the one you set with the hardware keys when being outside any application.
I tried with below method but it doesnt do anything

```
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.notif);
        AudioManager am = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        int volume_level = am.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM);
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(volume_level);
        mediaPlayer.start();
```

What do I need to change?

Comment: `mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(volume_level);` is incorrect. `setAudioStreamType` expects [a stream type](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#STREAM_ALARM), but you're giving it a volume index.

Answer (score 4):

You have to change this line

```
 mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(volume_level);
```

to this:

```
 mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM);
```

> setAudioStreamType()

Used to identify the type of audio stream

**AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM** is for alarm

**AudioManager.STREAM_DTMF** is for touch sounds

**AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC** is for music

**AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION** is for notification

**AudioManager.STREAM_RING** is for phone ring

**AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM** is for system sounds

**AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL** is for phone calls

Answer (score -2):

Please reffer offical doc [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html) to set or get the system volume of android device.

To set volume level to 20 you can use following code:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 20, 0);
```

Comment: I need to get the system volume, not set it myself to some static number